# Swapping columns in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *
def swap_columns(my_array, col1, col2):
    temp = my_array[:,col1]
    my_array[:,col1] = my_array[:,col2]
    my_array[:,col2] = temp
```

Then

```
swap_columns(data, 0, 1)
```

Doesn't work. However, calling the code directly

```
temp = my_array[:,0]
my_array[:,0] = my_array[:,1]
my_array[:,1] = temp
```

Does. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? The Error says "IndexError: 0-d arrays can only use a single () or a list of newaxes (and a single ...) as an index", which implies the arguments aren't ints? I already tried converting the cols to int but that didn't solve it.

Answer (score 130):

There are two issues here.  The first is that the `data` you pass to your function apparently isn't a two-dimensional NumPy array -- at least this is what the error message says.

The second issue is that the code does not do what you expect:

```
my_array = numpy.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
# array([[0, 1, 2],
#        [3, 4, 5],
#        [6, 7, 8]])
temp = my_array[:, 0]
my_array[:, 0] = my_array[:, 1]
my_array[:, 1] = temp
# array([[1, 1, 2],
#        [4, 4, 5],
#        [7, 7, 8]])
```

The problem is that Numpy [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) does not create copies of the actual data, but rather a view to the same data.  To make this work, you either have to copy explicitly

```
temp = numpy.copy(my_array[:, 0])
my_array[:, 0] = my_array[:, 1]
my_array[:, 1] = temp
```

or use [advanced slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

```
my_array[:, [0, 1]] = my_array[:, [1, 0]]
```

Comment: Advanced slicing does not appear to copy the data either.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Be assured, it does.  See the linked documentation, or try it yourself.

Comment: It certainly copies the data, but that means that the assignment assigns to a temporary object that is immediately discarded.

Comment: @AI0867 Only the advanced slicing on the right-hand side creates a copy. The advanced slicing in assignment-target position does not. You can try the code – it works just fine. (The reason for the different behaviour is that the `[]` operator in value context is handled by `__getitem__()`, while assignments with `[]` are handled by `__setitem__()`. It never makes sense to assign to a temporary copy, so the `__setitem__()` implementation for a NumPy array doesn't.)

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 45):

I find the following the fastest:

```
my_array[:, 0], my_array[:, 1] = my_array[:, 1], my_array[:, 0].copy()
```

Time analysis of:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.arange(900).reshape(30, 30)
```

is as follows:

```
%timeit my_array[:, 0], my_array[:, 1] = my_array[:, 1], my_array[:, 0].copy()
The slowest run took 15.05 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 µs per loop
```

The advanced slicing times are:

```
%timeit my_array[:,[0, 1]] = my_array[:,[1, 0]]
The slowest run took 7.38 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: Upvote for the copy() part, I was missing this in my code.

Answer (score 17):

An elegant way to swap the columns in NumPy is analogous to swapping two variables
in Python like so: `x, y = y, x`.

```
i, j = 0, 1
A.T[[i, j]] = A.T[[j, i]]  # swap the columns i and j
```

Suppose you have a numpy array `A` like this:

```
array([[ 0., -1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.]])
```

`A.T[[0, 1]] = A.T[[1, 0]]` will swap the first two columns:

```
array([[-1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.]])
```

Comment: Indeed very elegant and clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Building up on @Sven's answer:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
print my_array

[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]

def swap_cols(arr, frm, to):
    arr[:,[frm, to]] = arr[:,[to, frm]]

swap_cols(my_array, 0, 1)
print my_array

[[1 0 2]
 [4 3 5]
 [7 6 8]]

def swap_rows(arr, frm, to):
    arr[[frm, to],:] = arr[[to, frm],:]

my_array = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
swap_rows(my_array, 0, 2)
print my_array

[[6 7 8]
 [3 4 5]
 [0 1 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simultaneously swap columns and assign to a new variable, the most clear and concise way I could figure out how to do it was this:

```
import numpy as np
test_arr = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
swapped = np.concatenate((test_arr[:, [1,0]], test_arr[:, 2:]), axis=1)
```

Note, if the further columns don't exist it will concatenate an on an empty array, meaning it will just swap the first two columns.