# How to replace NaNs in array by other array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 Numpy arrays with the same length

```
array([ 0.9737068 ,  NaN,  NaN, ..., -0.64236529,
       -0.88137541, -0.78318609])

array([ 0.9 ,  0.7643,  0.61, ..., -0.64236529,
       -0.88137541, -0.78318609])
```

In the first array I have NaN values, how can I replace these NaN values with values from the second array. In this example my third array would be:

```
array([ 0.9737068 ,  Nan => 0.7643,  NaN => 0.61 , ..., -0.64236529,
       -0.88137541, -0.78318609])
```

Comment: Do you want a new array or to replace one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonic solution:

```
import numpy as np

def no_nans_arrays(array_w_nans,array_no_nans):
    return np.array([array_w_nans[i] if not np.isnan(array_w_nans[i]) else array_no_nans[i] for i in range(len(array_w_nans))])
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Numpy, the following works by applying a Boolean mask to both arrays:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.9737068, np.nan, np.nan, -0.64236529, -0.88137541, -0.78318609])
y = np.array([0.9, 0.7643, 0.61, -0.64236529, -0.88137541, -0.78318609])

x[np.isnan(x)] = y[np.isnan(x)]
```

Results in

```
In[1]:  x
Out[1]: 
array([ 0.9737068 ,  0.7643    ,  0.61      , -0.64236529, -0.88137541,
       -0.78318609])
```

N.B. Running with `%timeit`, this solution takes < 4µs in repeated runs, vs. the other two Numpy solutions (at time of writing this) which both take 20-25µs

Answer (score 0):

If not numpy, you might find this function helpful:

```
def swap(A,B,i,j):
    TEMP_B = B[j]
    B[j] = A[i]
    A[i] = TEMP_B
    return A,B
```

Iterate over your first array, `if element is NaN`, then use swap.

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615017/swapping-two-elements-between-two-lists-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

```py
res = np.array([ a1 if not np.isnan(a1) else b1 for a1,b1 in zip(a, b) ])
```

`np.isnan` returns False if the given element in the `np.array` is `np.NaN`

Comment: a more Pythonic solution would be ```if not np.isnan(a1)``` instead of ```if np.isnan(a1)==False```