# How to change array rows places whithouth numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

Hello everyone here is my code:

```
n =[[34,2,55,24,22],[31,22,4,7,333],[87,74,44,12,48]]
for r in n:
   for c in r:
      print(c,end = " ")
   print()
   
sums=[]

for i in n:
  sum=0
  for num in i:
    sum+=int(num)
  sums.append(sum)
print(*sums)

print(*(min(row) for row in n))
```

And here is what it prints out:

```
34 2 55 24 22 
31 22 4 7 333 
87 74 44 12 48 
137 397 265
2 4 12
```

I need to change row whith smallest number and bigest number so it means row 1 and 2 like this:

```
31 22 4 7 333
34 2 55 24 22 
87 74 44 12 48

#end result needs to look like this:

34 2 55 24 22 
31 22 4 7 333 
87 74 44 12 48 
137 397 265
2 4 12

31 22 4 7 333
34 2 55 24 22 
87 74 44 12 48
```

Please help me i cant use numpy because it doesnt work I tried using it but all it gives are errors.

Comment: It's hard to see what you want, please be more explicit. Sorting rows by sum? You create `sums`, but then never use it. And the "end results" use numbers which never occured before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap slices of Numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933577/swap-slices-of-numpy-arrays)

Comment: No i need to change row whith smallest number whith row whith bigest number when printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the list with max at the first index and the one with the min at the end,

```py
maxs = [max(i) for i in n]
mins = [min(i) for i in n]

max_idx = maxs.index(max(maxs))
min_idx = mins.index(min(mins))
n[max_idx], n[min_idx] = n[min_idx], n[max_idx]
# you need to think about when min_idx = max_idx 
# or when there's more than one max/min
```

If you don't mind `numpy`, you can use:

```py
max_idx = np.argmax(np.max(n, axis=1))
min_idx = np.argmin(np.min(n, axis=1))
```

Comment: thx its exatly how i needed