# random.shuffle erasing items and not shuffling properly

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle

I am initializing two multivariate gaussian distributions like so and trying to implement a machine learning algorithm to draw a decision boundary between the classes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import random

mu0 = [-2,-2]
mu1 = [2, 2]
cov = np.array([[1, 0],[0, 1]]) 
X = np.random.randn(10,2)
L = np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
Y0 = mu0 + X@L.T 
Y1 = mu1 + X@L.T
```

I have two separated circles and I am trying to stack Y0 and Y1, shuffle them, and then break them into training and testing splits. First I append the class labels to the data, and then stack.

```
n,m = Y1.shape
class0 = np.zeros((n,1))
class1 = np.ones((n,1))
Y_0 = np.hstack((Y0,class0))
Y_1 = np.hstack((Y1,class1))

data = np.vstack((Y_0,Y_1))
```

Now when i try to call `random.shuffle(data)` the zero class takes over and I get a small number of class one instances.

```
random.shuffle(data)
```

Here is my data before shuffling:

```
print(data)
[[-3.16184428 -1.89491433  0.        ]
 [ 0.2710061  -1.41000924  0.        ]
 [-3.50742027 -2.04238337  0.        ]
 [-1.39966859 -1.57430259  0.        ]
 [-0.98356629 -3.02299622  0.        ]
 [-0.49583458 -1.64067853  0.        ]
 [-2.62577229 -2.32941225  0.        ]
 [-1.16005269 -2.76429318  0.        ]
 [-1.88618759 -2.79178253  0.        ]
 [-1.34790868 -2.10294791  0.        ]
 [ 0.83815572  2.10508567  1.        ]
 [ 4.2710061   2.58999076  1.        ]
 [ 0.49257973  1.95761663  1.        ]
 [ 2.60033141  2.42569741  1.        ]
 [ 3.01643371  0.97700378  1.        ]
 [ 3.50416542  2.35932147  1.        ]
 [ 1.37422771  1.67058775  1.        ]
 [ 2.83994731  1.23570682  1.        ]
 [ 2.11381241  1.20821747  1.        ]
 [ 2.65209132  1.89705209  1.        ]]
```

and after shufffling:

```
data
array([[-0.335667  , -0.60826166,  0.        ],
       [-0.335667  , -0.60826166,  0.        ],
       [-0.335667  , -0.60826166,  0.        ],
       [-0.335667  , -0.60826166,  0.        ],
       [-2.22547604, -1.62833794,  0.        ],
       [-3.3287687 , -2.37694753,  0.        ],
       [-3.2915737 , -1.31558952,  0.        ],
       [-2.23912202, -1.54625136,  0.        ],
       [-0.335667  , -0.60826166,  0.        ],
       [-2.23912202, -1.54625136,  0.        ],
       [-2.11217077, -2.70157476,  0.        ],
       [-3.25714184, -2.7679462 ,  0.        ],
       [-3.2915737 , -1.31558952,  0.        ],
       [-2.22547604, -1.62833794,  0.        ],
       [ 0.73756329,  1.46127708,  1.        ],
       [ 1.88782923,  1.29842524,  1.        ],
       [ 1.77452396,  2.37166206,  1.        ],
       [ 1.77452396,  2.37166206,  1.        ],
       [ 3.664333  ,  3.39173834,  1.        ],
       [ 3.664333  ,  3.39173834,  1.        ]])
```

Why is `random.shuffle` deleting my data? I just need all twenty rows to be shuffled, but it is repeating lines and i am losing data. i'm not setting `random.shuffle` to a variable and am simply just calling `random.shuffle(data)`. Are there any other ways to simply shuffle my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the swap method used by the `random.shuffle` does not work in ndarray:

```
# Python 3.10.7 random.py
class Random(_random.Random):
    ...
    def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
        ...
        if random is None:
            randbelow = self._randbelow
            for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
                # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
                j = randbelow(i + 1)
                x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]    # <----------------
        ...
    ...
```

Using index on multi-dimensional array will result in a view instead of a copy, which will prevent the swap from working properly. For more information, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933577/swap-slices-of-numpy-arrays).

**Better choice** [`numpy.random.Generator.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.shuffle.html):

```
>>> data
array([[-1.88985877, -2.97312795,  0.        ],
       [-1.52352452, -2.19633099,  0.        ],
       [-2.06297352, -1.36627294,  0.        ],
       [-1.47460488, -2.09410403,  0.        ],
       [-1.18753167, -1.71069966,  0.        ],
       [-1.92878766, -1.19545861,  0.        ],
       [-2.4858627 , -2.66525855,  0.        ],
       [-2.97169999, -1.46985506,  0.        ],
       [-2.11395907, -2.19108576,  0.        ],
       [-2.63976951, -1.66742147,  0.        ],
       [ 2.11014123,  1.02687205,  1.        ],
       [ 2.47647548,  1.80366901,  1.        ],
       [ 1.93702648,  2.63372706,  1.        ],
       [ 2.52539512,  1.90589597,  1.        ],
       [ 2.81246833,  2.28930034,  1.        ],
       [ 2.07121234,  2.80454139,  1.        ],
       [ 1.5141373 ,  1.33474145,  1.        ],
       [ 1.02830001,  2.53014494,  1.        ],
       [ 1.88604093,  1.80891424,  1.        ],
       [ 1.36023049,  2.33257853,  1.        ]])
>>> rng = np.random.default_rng()
>>> rng.shuffle(data, 0)
>>> data
array([[-1.92878766, -1.19545861,  0.        ],
       [-2.97169999, -1.46985506,  0.        ],
       [ 2.07121234,  2.80454139,  1.        ],
       [ 1.36023049,  2.33257853,  1.        ],
       [ 1.93702648,  2.63372706,  1.        ],
       [-2.11395907, -2.19108576,  0.        ],
       [-2.63976951, -1.66742147,  0.        ],
       [ 1.02830001,  2.53014494,  1.        ],
       [ 2.11014123,  1.02687205,  1.        ],
       [ 1.88604093,  1.80891424,  1.        ],
       [-1.47460488, -2.09410403,  0.        ],
       [ 2.52539512,  1.90589597,  1.        ],
       [-1.18753167, -1.71069966,  0.        ],
       [-1.88985877, -2.97312795,  0.        ],
       [ 2.81246833,  2.28930034,  1.        ],
       [-2.06297352, -1.36627294,  0.        ],
       [ 1.5141373 ,  1.33474145,  1.        ],
       [-2.4858627 , -2.66525855,  0.        ],
       [-1.52352452, -2.19633099,  0.        ],
       [ 2.47647548,  1.80366901,  1.        ]])
```

<sub>In this example, [`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) also works normally because OP just requires shuffling along the first axis, but `numpy.random.Generator.shuffle` is the recommended usage in the new code and supports shuffling along other axis.</sub>