# Replace a column in a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, variable-assignment

I'm trying to inter-change columns from 2 matrices, but my assignment seems to not be doing it.

```
crom1 = crossover_list[0][0][:,j]
print('c1', crom1)
crom2 = crossover_list[1][0][:,j]
print('c2', crom2)

crossover_list[0][0][:,j] = crom2

print(crossover_list[1][0][:,j])
crossover_list[1][0][:,j] = crom1
print(crossover_list[1][0][:,j])
```

And this is what comes out:
[image]

Any suggestions?

LE: I also tried the following, with no success:

```
aux = crossover_list[0][0][:,j]
crossover_list[0][0][:,j] = crossover_list[1][0][:,j]
crossover_list[1][0][:,j] = aux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aux = numpy.copy(crossover_list[0][0][:,j])
crossover_list[0][0][:,j] = crossover_list[1][0][:,j]
crossover_list[1][0][:,j] = aux
```

Seems to work like this (based on [Swapping columns in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857927/swapping-columns-in-a-numpy-array) )

Comment: Your code and question would be simpler if you used `x=crossover_list[0][0]`, and `y=crossover_list[1][0]`, and made sure they were both `ndarray` (as opposed to lists or list of lists).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can do that, as I'm switching columns between 2 matrices, but not all the columns.